# Outlook 2013: Visual Studio Plugin to get access to email content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I'm trying to write a plugin for Outlook 2013 that processes content of emails.

So far, I've created an Outlook Addin-project in Visual Studio. Furthermore, I created a ribbon button, with

```
RibbonType = Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read
```

to show the button only when an email is read.

Is it possible get access to the email in order to e.g. show the subject or the content (consisting of plain text)?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, Ribbon ControlEventArgs e) 
     { 
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( ... ); 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RibbonControlEventArgs.Control` property to get to the `RiibbonControl` object. You can then use the `IRibbonControl.Context` property and cast it to the `Inspector` object (for inspectors) or `Explorer` (for the Explorer buttons). Once you have the Inspector object, use the `Inspector.CurrentItem` property.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dmitry for your help!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
{
    var mailItem = ((Inspector) e.Control.Context).CurrentItem;
    MessageBox.Show(mailItem.Subject);
    MessageBox.Show(mailItem.Body);
}
```